# How to compare two Compare of two std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set

When I use the container std::set,I want to compare set's Compare.One definition of set as follows:

```
template < class T,                        // set::key_type/value_type
           class Compare = less<T>,        // set::key_compare/value_compare
           class Alloc = allocator<T>      // set::allocator_type
           > class set;
```

We know Compare is the sort crietion for elements in set,it can be a function object in STL or user supply it.Only one request for function object is to realiz opeartor().In program I can get Compare use the public member function `value_compare value_comp() const`
My question is how to distinguish the sort crietion of two set(Two set use same sort crietion or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) has a `key_compare` typedef to `Compare` so simply:

```
std::is_same<decltype(set_a)::key_compare, decltype(set_b)::key_compare>::value
```

Or in a `struct`:

```
template<typename Set1, typename Set2>
struct is_same_comparator: public std::is_same<typename Set1::key_compare,
                                               typename Set2::key_compare> { };

using S1 = std::set<int>;
using S2 = std::set<int, std::greater<int>>;

static_assert(is_same_comparator<S1, S1>{}, "Oops!");
static_assert(is_same_comparator<S1, S2>{}, "Oops!");
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/g/IFR4GT)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

template<typename t> class comparator_type;

template<typename v1, typename c1, typename a1>
class comparator_type<std::set<v1, c1, a1>> {

 public:

    typedef c1 type_t;
};

template<typename set1, typename set2>
constexpr bool is_same_comparators()
{
    return std::is_same<typename comparator_type<set1>::type_t,
                typename comparator_type<set2>::type_t>
        ::value;
}


int main()
{
    std::set<int> a, b;
    std::set<int, std::greater<int>> c;

    std::cout << is_same_comparators<decltype(a), decltype(b)>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_same_comparators<decltype(a), decltype(c)>() << std::endl;
}
```

Resulting output:

```
1
0
```

Comment: Why do you need this `comparator_type` intermediate structure when you can access the comparatore type using `typename set1::key_compare`?

Comment: Thank you very much,before I forget

Answer (score 0):

Get the Compare of std::set by `key_comp` directly, then compare them with `std::is_same`

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

int main( )
{
    std::set<int> a;
    std::set<int, std::greater<int> > b;
    std::set<int, std::less<int> > c;
    std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(a.key_comp()), decltype(b.key_comp()) >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(a.key_comp()), decltype(c.key_comp()) >::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I just want to make a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if two comparison functions are the same type (as the other answers show), but that doesn't mean that they are the same function. The following code compiles w/o errors, even though they use different sort criteria.

```
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

bool g(int a, int b) { return a > b; }
bool l(int a, int b) { return a < b; }

int main () {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g), decltype(l)>::value, "" );

    {
    typedef std::set<int, bool(*)(int, int)>  Set1;
    Set1 sg(g);
    Set1 sl(l);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(sg.key_comp()), decltype(sl.key_comp())>::value, "" );
    sg.insert({1,2,3});
    for (int i : sg) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    sl.insert({1,2,3});
    for (int i : sl) std::cout << i << " "; std::cout << "\n";
    }

    {
    typedef std::function<bool(int, int)> Comp;
    Comp fg(g);
    Comp fl(l);
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(fg), decltype(fl)>::value, "" );

    typedef std::set<int, Comp>  Set2;
    Set2 sg(fg);
    Set2 sl(fl);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(sg.key_comp()), decltype(sl.key_comp())>::value, "" );
    }
}
```

and prints:

```
3 2 1
1 2 3
```